# Rails: 2 user ids in a single table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to make it so the following will return all received messages:

```
current_user.messages.received
```

And the following will make it so I will see all sent messages:

```
current_user.messages.sent
```

The problem I am having is that I am not sure how to specify that 2 columns in a single table both represent the foreign key for a user. How do I associate both sender_id and recipient_id to a user?

**db/schema.rb**

```
  create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "notification",      null: false
    t.integer  "user_id",      null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "recipient_id", null: false
  end
```

**app/models/message.rb**

```
class Messages < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :user
end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, each message has exactly one sender and possible many receivers.
So your models could be:

```
class Messages < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :receivers, class_name: 'User'  
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User'  
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :received_messages, class_name: 'Message'
end
```

You need an join table for the "sent messages":

```
class CreateJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :messages
  end
end
```

Now you can access your sent and received messages:

```
current_user.messages # sent messages
current_userreceived_messages
```